# Rails - Primary & Secondary phone numbers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations

I'm kind of up in the air about how to handle a fairly simple problem in Rails.  I need to record phone numbers for users, and I would like to add the ability for users to select one phone number as a primary contact number.  I already have a PhoneNumber class (polymorphic, as businesses also have phone numbers), so that's all set up.

I figure that I can do this one of two ways:

1. Set up an association where a user has_many phone numbers, and add a field to indicate whether or not that phone number is the primary number for that user.
2. Set up a separate attribute for primary phone number (as user would have only one), and then have secondary phone numbers as as has_many association.

In either case, I will have to add some code to alter the properties of all of the associated phone numbers when a user designates a new one as primary.  I'm just curious if more experienced users feel that there is clearly a best practice here.

Comment: since the user may have many phone numbers, the has_many :phone_numbers association is the one i would use.

Comment: Surase - I've played with it, and I like your implementation more.  If you'd submit it as an answer, I'd happily select it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since the user may have many phone numbers, the has_many :phone_numbers association is the one i would use. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to make two Models `PrimaryNumber` and `SecondaryNumber`. Relationship would be  `User` has_one `PrimaryNumber`, `User` has_many (has_one depending upon how many number you would allow) `SecondaryNumber`. That way you can get

```
 user = User.find(key)
 user.primary_number
 user.secondary_number(s)
```

For sake of simplicity as there is only one `Primary Number`, you can have column in `User` table itself `primary_number`. Then, you won't need `PrimaryNumber` table/model